# Yield curve to price bonds

Tags: bonds, government-bonds, yield, treasury

I am having a hard time finding books/materials that would teach yield curve pricing using real-world problems/examples

I would like to understand if can I use the below treasury yield data (I believe those are spot rates, also called) to price any treasury bond matching the maturity?

say;
I want to price bond maturing in exactly 2 years as of Nov/03/2022,

I take the below zero yields/spot rates,

discount principal+coupon at the 2 year yield, 1st coupon at the 6mon yield, 2nd coupon at the 12 mon yield, and the 3rd coupon at 18 mon yield? all from the picture below.

[https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2020](https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value=2022)

[image: treasury par yields as of 11/03/2022]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what books you're using or what I would tell you that's any different, but bonds are priced using discounted cash flow (DCF) models. For a fixed rate bond, if you have discount rates (the Treasury "spot rates" for a government bond), then you just calculate the present value of each cash flow (coupons plus final redemption):

```
    C1         C2         C3                Cn + P
---------  ---------  ---------  + ... +   ---------
(1+r1)^t1  (1+r2)^t2  (1+r3)^t3            (1+rn)^tn
```

In your case, you have two coupon periods and the 4th coupon plus par amount (`P`) with known discount rates, so all you need to do is discount each cash flow to find the fair price of the bond.  For the 3rd coupon, you can do a simple linear interpolation or a more complicated interpolation (polynomial, exponential, cubic spline, etc.) to find a rate between the 12 month and 24 month rates. There's not a "right" answer for that, but the difference in price shouldn't be massive just by choosing a different interpolation method.

Comment: @D Stanley thank you for the reply, I forgot to mention that 18 mon rate is not published, but has to be interpolated. So what I wasn't sure, whether those rates published are spot rates, yield par rayes = spot rate? so say my coupon is 2% I would 102/ 1.0471^4 + 2/1+interpolation^3 + 2/1.0478^2 + 2/1.0457^1

Comment: Correct - I mention that in my answer. The data you show is the "yield curve" and is what you would use (and interpolate) to find the bond price.